# libtool automake: LIBADD broken with static linking?

Tags: autotools, automake, libtool

I have a program `aa` that depends on `libbb` which depends on `libcc`.

In libb's Makefile.am I have added

```
libbb_la_LIBADD = -lcc
```

In aa's Makefile I have added

```
aa_LDADD = -lbb
```

This works wonderful in the default case.

But I needed static linking, so I ran all the configures with `--disable-shared`.
Unfortunately when compiling `aa` I got:

> libb_source.c: undefined reference to libcc_symbol

Any ideas what is missing?

**Update:** Don't think of specifying dependencies like this if you are crosscompiling and using a stagingdir.

Comment: If 'libbb' and 'libcc' are built with libtool, the `LIBADD` and `LDADD` variables should list `libbb.la` rather than `-lbb`. You might conditionally add `-static` to the `AM_LDFLAGS` variable.

Comment: @BrettHale Don't put answers in the comments, my friend! :)

Comment: But how else should I specify my dependencies if I'm crosscompiling and using a staging dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass the link flag. Give it the name of the libtool archive and let automake work it out:

```
aa_LDADD = bb/libbb.la
```

In case you ever want to build Windows DLLs, you might also want to put `-no-undefined` in `libbb_la_LDFLAGS`.

Comment: What to do, if the location of libbb.la is not relative to Makefile.am but somewhere in the directories add with -L to LDFLAGS?

Comment: Is libbb.la actually part of your project or is it some installed system library?

Comment: it is some installed system library. LIBADD does not seem to check LDFLAGS. The only solution i currently see is write a configure test that gets the absolute path to the .la file. But this seems a bit hackish.

Comment: Does libbb come with a pkg-config `.pc` file? If you get the LDFLAGS using `pkg-config`, they correctly name the library and its dependencies.

Comment: i don't think pkg-config will help me, as i need the absolute path to the .la file, which AFAIK can not print with pkg-config. The linker does not look at LDFLAGS when trying to link against the .la file.  I am currently looking at libltdl, to see if it can solve my problem

Comment: No, but `pkg-config` will list `-lcc` if it's been set up correctly (it will read in all the dependencies and list them all when you ask it for linking flags).